# Has anyone had success with Voice Chat in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Starcraft 2 has an in-game microphone feature (push-to-talk), but none of my party members have had success in getting the Battle.net voice chat to work.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I haven't. With pressing the button or having it on auto I can see volume meter going up and down, but my fiends don't hear me. But I didn't spend more than a minute trying to get it to work. My friends and I already use skype for other gaming.

Comment: Have a look [at this question for interesting alternatives](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/pc-voice-chat-software-closed)

Comment: Never could get voice working in either WoW or SC2. With everything at max level, I just hear hardly anything, and my friends cannot do better on their side. I always had to get back on an alternative, either Skype, Teamspeak, Ventrilo, GTalk...

Answer (score 5):

It's been very hit or miss for me, so my team has just been using Skype.

[Here's another (closed) question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/pc-voice-chat-software-closed) that mentions several other alternatives

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a different method of communicating.  It's just fubar'd in SC2.

Answer (score 2):

I have never had a problem with voice chat.
I could only suggest increasing the number of voice channels (should be under "Sound" in the game Options menu),
or try explicitly setting the Voice Input and Output devices.

---

A week or so ago, I was playing 2v2 team games with a friend, I was dissatisfied with the voice chat quality. Despite he game's default setup for killing the music and bringing the game sounds down to 25%, his voice coming out of the same speakers was just "fuzzy", and I didn't like it.

I went downstairs and grabbed a USB->Headphone adapter device I have had for a while, and plugged it into out iMac. I set up a small 3.1 speaker set I had in the room and plugged them into the adapter. Afterwards, configure the game to EXPLICITLY use Game Music/Sounds via the Built-In Speakers, hit the Voice tab, and configure it to use the "USB Audio Device" for output. (This was kind of a crap-shoot task to do, because the Output Device list listed not one, not two, but ***FOUR*** "USB Audio Device"s. It was simple given the ability to tell my friend "start talking and I'll tell you when to stop" so I can test the ports.)

Now, I could not only turn the Voice Output up louder, but given that it was travelling out of a different physical device, it seemed a lot cleaner. This is anecdotal at best, and I'm sure I could have cleaned it up by turning Voice Output up, setting the sound/music to be cut harder, but frankly I'm enjoying this setup.

Ultimately, I have an external USB Mic set up for my own speech as well, game sounds and music coming out the built in speakers, and all game voice chat comes out a separate set of speakers. It's a busy/packed, but ultimately higher quality setup. (Again, anecdotally at best, but I still prefer it.)

Comment: You say you have never had a problem with voice chat in SC2, then go on to explain the problems you had with voice chat in SC2...?

Comment: I say I've never had a problem hearing/speaking, other than the quality of it was a little muffled, and I'm seriously being picky in saying that. We had a whole conversation before I changed things around. But, it was just a bit muffled, so I moved voice output to a dedicated set of speakers. It just sounded better to me.

Compared to the complaints of "doesn't work at all", my issue isn't anywhere close.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the voicechat in SC2, but have you tried [Ventrilo](http://www.ventrilo.com/)??

It's supposed to be very highly regarded in the online gaming community, as a means for verbal communication.

Comment: +1: I've been using Vent for years. I pay for a small private server through a company called Typefrag (http://typefrag.com/) ...It's so cheap as to be laughable, and the company has been very reliable. I've used vent extensively with SCII, and have had no issues with latency, even using a high-end codec. (One of the guys in my gaming group uses a Mac for vent, so I had to use a high end codec...No lag issues at all).

Comment: You'll want to watch out for Vent Harassers though.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like an ad

Comment: It's not.  I've never even used vent.  This question is 10 years old, I would recommend Discord now

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to note that [Team Speak](http://teamspeak.com/) is free AND they have a free public server.  I've used it for SC2 and D&D games.  Works great!

Answer (score 0):

It has been working on and off ever since it came out in Beta. Release day of SC2 it worked, but i have not had it working since day 2... They really need to fix that; i am sick of using vent!

This is true for both automatic and push to talk.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help in your case; I'm using a standard UK layout keyboard and have my push-to-talk key left at default: grave/tilde. Usually when games refer to the tilde key (<kbd>~</kbd>), they mean <kbd>`</kbd>, since it's located in the upper left like the tilde is  on US keyboards. Neither that or my actual tilde key works and I had assumed I was experiencing the problems other answerers cite. While typing I realised that the key actually used to activate voice - at least for me - is <kbd>'</kbd> (<kbd>@</kbd> when used with <kbd>shift</kbd>).

Comment: What is the markdown needed to produce key icons?

Comment: StackExchange uses the HTML kbd tag for that, as I recall.

Comment: Strangely, on a US keyboard tilde is shift-grave.  I have no idea why companies say tilde since they actually mean grave.  Too much confusion with apostrophe, I guess.

Comment: @Powerlord it probably doesn't help that most people don't call it "grave" either.  I've always called that character a backtick.

Answer (score 0):

Voice chat in SC2 is broken at the moment.

Hopefully they will fix this soon, as it is quite annoying.

Until then, if you want to utilize voice chat to communicate with your team mates you will need to utilize a 3rd party application, a list of those can be found **[here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/pc-voice-chat-software/2833#2833)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using voice chat in Sc2 everyday. I'm from South Africa and my friend in the US. We use the chat feature every time and its works very well in our 2v2 games. We have set it to voice activated so we don't have to hit a key every time we want to chat. We even had 4 ppl chatting last weekend.

Invite all to party and chat away

DeckoZA

Answer (score 0):

I use Skype for voice chat while I game - for that I use Overwolf. With Overwolf I'm able to use Skype (and other cool stuff like in-game browser) with Starcraft 2 without using alt+tab. It also features a cool UI especially for gamers (PTT and stuff).

Try it out - [Overwolf - Use Skype in Game](http://www.overwolf.com/apps/skype/)

Comment: I've tried overwolf and it kinda reduced my FPS significantly, did you have the same experience or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it work until I did some portforwarding in the router menu. Check out the Battlenet FAQ on it.

The hassle doesn't seem to  be worth it, really. Sound quality is so poor that my team stopped talking mid-game and went back to typing. I think we shall go back to Skype because, even though it's a hassle, at least the quality is reliable and you don't have to ask/repeat things 10 times every single time you say something.

Answer (score 0):

For mac, I has to do the following:

1. **Enable voice chat** in Options > Voice Chat. Use the testing utility to make sure your mic setup works. I recommend using
   voice-activated. But set up the hotkey anyway so you can try it both
   ways:
2. **Hotkey:** Options > Hotkeys (it's lower left) > Global; expand UI, find **Push-to-talk**. When I clicked this initially it said `Key/OEM8`. I don't know what that is but it didn't work. Generally it's set to Backtick: <kbd>`</kbd> - that won't conflict with anything (to the left of <kbd>1</kbd>). Bind the hotkey.

That should do it. In a party, your allies can hear you, but your opponents can't. If you are playing against someone in your party, they won't be able to hear you. The voice chat should work always - in the menus, even on loading screens. It's lower quality audio, but in my experience it works pretty well.

Answer (score -2):

It's push-to-talk, which is not immediately obvious ...

Comment: This is not the problem most of us are having.  Changing to automatic doesn't fix it, nor does pressing tilde.

Comment: Are you sure it's the tilde doesn't need shift or something else on your keyboard @Jaydles?

Comment: @Ivo, I'm pretty sure.   Changing to automatic makes it pick up sound, eliminating the need for tilde.   And in both cases, (pressing tilde when talking or going to automatic,) the colored bars light up indicating that it hears the sound.  But even in the chat sound test, it doesn't output it, regardless of output selected.

Comment: I don't have a tilde key on my keyboard, you insensitive clods!