# Why doesn't my in-game microphone feature work?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone had success with Voice Chat in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4695/has-anyone-had-success-with-voice-chat-in-starcraft-2)

Starcraft 2 has an in-game microphone feature (push-to-talk), but it simply doesn't work.

My microphone is functioning outside of the game and when I talk I can see that it picks up my voice (the microphone waves move), but no one can hear me. Also, the microphone test does not work. My settings are fine, and it's not muted or anything.

Any idea on what to do?

Comment: I agree- this is a dupe, and I voted to close, but once it is, can someone A) merge these answers, and B) add the word "microphone" to the other posts title, so it's easier to find?

Comment: @Jaydles: I added the microphone mention to the other question. I don't think answers should be merged, both of them look like comments more than answering the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You're not crazy. It doesn't work for a TON of people.

And it's infuriating, because the test clearly indicates that the game can access your machine's mic and pick up sound.

Answer (score 2):

I have friends who use [Ventrilo](http://www.ventrilo.com/) instead.  Many of them site that the in-game microphone feature is buggy and they prefer to use something they already know works.

Comment: I use it too, but some people prefer a free option. You can always use Skype with your friends.