# imac voice chat not working with Starcraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2, macos, technical-issues, voice-chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone had success with Voice Chat in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4695/has-anyone-had-success-with-voice-chat-in-starcraft-2)

This is for a friend. He has all the latest drivers. The game sound works fine, but he can't hear the rest of the party and we can't hear him. When he runs a voice test in sc2's voice test area, it does detect the input.

TL;DR sound works for everything but voice chat. he can't hear us chat and we can't hear him.

Here's a link to where its happening for someone else:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=979472

Comment: Well, the OP is asking about it for the Mac specifically. So I wouldn't call it a duplicate. The majority of questions asked on gaming.SE are for PCs.

Comment: @sunpech I don't think the other question is PC-only.

Comment: @JavadocMD I think questions unless specified as Mac, is PC/Windows.

Comment: This isn't just a Mac issue.  Voice chat hasn't worked for many people, myself included, ever.  Even in beta voice chat was a fail.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/when-is-a-duplicate-question-not-a-duplicate/12184#12184  A duplicate question is one that receives the same answer.  Since this isn't a mac issue and both questions have the same answer: vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for all the non-answers, and the inappropriate closing. Having someone answer the question the same doesn't constitute a duplicate question. Having an ACTUAL SAME ANSWER would but this is not the case. Voice chat does work for me, just not my friend, and he's using an IMac. "Voice chat doesn't work" may be the same answer, but its not a correct answer. Mine does, his doesn't. There are variables at play here, and stackexchange is designed so that someone who actually knows what they're talking about can answer it. "It doesn't work" and "maybe blizzard will fix it" helps no one.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't just an imac problem. Voice chat in SC2 is broken at the moment.

Hopefully they will fix this soon, as it it quite annoying.

Until then, if you want to utilize voice chat to communicate with your team mates you will need to utilize a 3rd party application, a list of those can be found **[here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/pc-voice-chat-software/2833#2833)**

Comment: +1 Although they link is labeled as PC software, many if not all of those voice-chat alternatives also work on Mac.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that the problem is more widespread than Imacs. People are having issues with voice chat, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the issues are related.

Answer (score 0):

Voice chat doesn't seem to work on the PC either as you can see in:

- [Starcraft 2: Microphone doesn't work in-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/starcraft-2-microphone-doesnt-work-in-game)
- [Has anyone had success with Voice Chat in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4695/has-anyone-had-success-with-voice-chat-in-starcraft-2).

I'd recommend your friend try [Ventrilo](http://www.ventrilo.com/) and/or [Skype](http://www.skype.com).

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to toss out the fact that [TeamSpeak](http://www.teamspeak.com/) provides a free server that you can chat in.  I've played SC2 and run online D&D games using this free service.  Not to shabby!